# Jet engine thrust

Tags: forces

I have been searching on and off for years for the answer to the following question. If a party balloon is inflated, and the valve or stem, is released, the air rushes out of that side of the balloon leaving a low pressure area on that side or wall of the balloon. Meanwhile, the wall of the front of the balloon experiences, a higher pressure from the gases within since it is not released in that direction. Therefore the balloon is driven forward by higher pressure on one side than the other. This can be visualized for a rocket engine also. But since a ram jet is open at both ends, how can the rocket principal apply?  The high-pressure air is coming in from the front to cause compression, but it seems that the combustion would neutralize any compression that is happening, and there would be net zero thrust, just an explosion.

Even in a jet engine, which has blades to compress the air before it reaches the combustion chamber, it would seem that the force of the combustion would neutralize the compression effect resulting in the engine stalling.   This seems to be a situation where the engine pulls itself up by its own bootstraps!

I understand the principle of Newtonian, action and reaction, but I don’t see how this applies in this case. With the balloon, the action of the air rushing out of the stem, lowering the pressure on that side, results in the reaction of the front wall being pushed forward.  My understanding is that the rush of air coming out of the back of the balloon, pushing on the air behind the balloon, has nothing to do with it. It is the pressure within the balloon that is pushing it forward.  I read a similar post about this on your site, but it does not exactly address this question.

Comment: > *it seems that the combustion would neutralize any compression that is happening* Combustion produces much hotter gas than the gas entering the engine.  That hot gas is expelled in one direction only. That expelled stream of hot gas has much higher momentum than the gas entering the engine.

Comment: what causes it to expel in one direction only?  put a little gun powder in the center of a pipe and light it.  it will blow out both ends of the pipe.  put a cap on one end and it only blows out in one direction.  what is the "cap" that causes the jet to push out the gas in one direction only?

Comment: Jet engine combustion chamber is not a pipe with a cap, it is asymmetric and designed to expel gases in one direction only. Existing stream of incoming air helps with that. This is more of an engineering question.

Comment: please refer to the balloon example I mentioned.  this is a physics question.  if the pressure in the balloon is released on one side then the other side has the most pressure on it which drives the balloon in that direction.  what does the RAM jet engine push on to accomplish this?

Comment: Jet engine pushes on the plane body. Inside the jet engine, the hot expanding gases push on the engine in direction of flight. This is so both in ordinary mode and in RAM jet mode. The engine combustion chamber does not work in still air, the air moves through it with high speed in one direction. In RAM jet mode the hot gases can't move upstream, the air stream is too fast.

Comment: It may help to think of how the rocket engine produces thrust. Jet engine is very similar: it is different in that it allows the atmospheric air to come inside the combustion chamber, but the momentum exchange works very similarly - expanding gases push on the chamber and produce thrust in one direction.

Comment: thanks, but i still do not understand how the combustion does not simply cause the engine to stall.  air is rushing in from the front but the tremendous combustion force is pushing against the incoming air, not pushing on the plane body.

Comment: a rocket engine has a bell housing that the combustion is pushing against which propels the rocket forward.  just like the balloon the pressure of combustion is forced or released out the back because it is blocked form the front by the bell housing.  the bell housing is attached to the rocket body and thus propels it forward.  it is a contained explosion that can only exit in one direction. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) in a ram jet what keeps the explosion from pushing on the incoming air causing a stall?  if pressure is pushing on a bell housing i can see the method of propulsion but the jet, ram jet in particular, is only pushing on the incoming air.  i can see that MAYBE the combustion could be pushing on the compressor fan blades in a turbojet but this does not explain t ram jet.

Comment: Since ramjet works without compressor stage only if speed is high enough, it seems the ramjet mode is such that the incoming air is fast and compressed enough, so that the combustion does not reverse the air stream. Reversal of stream may be a concern in theory, but the engine details are obviously designed to prevent it; this is engineering. The hot gas pushes on the internal walls of the engine, both in standard jet and in ramjet. The combustion chamber need not be perfect-bell-shaped or closed off on one end to experience net thrust from pressure forces from the expelled gases.

Comment: Instead of a cap or closed end of the combustion chamber, the fast and high-pressurized incoming gas can function as the body blocking the hot gases from moving in reverse. So the air in the incoming stream itself acts as a sort of a cap or blocking body.

Comment: i agree that this is more of a physics then an engineering question, and thanks for your input.  So then, in the ramjet, is the pressure of the incoming air higher than in the combustion chamber? if not then it seems that the combustion force would cause a stall of the incoming air since it is basically an open tube with contoured sides. if it IS higher then perhaps that is what constitutes the forward balloon wall or bell that the reaction is pushing against.  but then it is only pushing against air and not the body of the engine as in a rocket.

Comment: The principle is physics, and it is simple - combustion produces fast stream of gas in one direction, this gas exerts net force on the chamber, both directly and via intermediary body, the incoming air stream. The details (how the chamber must be constructed to prevent reversal of flow, or intake of exhaust) are more of an engineering area.

Comment: i guess what has confused me is what causes the stream of gas to be produced in one direction

Comment: cont'd - what causes it to go in one direction is the question because that is what exerts the opposite reaction on the system and drives it forward.  I suppose I can envision the inside of the combustion chamber as designed to restrict the forward flow of the gas by chamber design.  i was just having difficulty seeing how a less-than-complete wall of resistance could produce the amount of forward thrust needed.

Comment: I think in ramjet without compressor fins, the incoming air stream is what prevents the hot gas from going upstream. This will work only if the incoming air is fast and dense enough.

Comment: it is hard for me to imagine that the incoming air could possibly have more pressure than the tremendous combustion pushing against it, (and all sides of the combustion chamber and exhaust).  even so i can't see how the force of the combustion is not in part just pushing against the incoming air which would not act on the frame to drive it forward.  i just have to accept that the design is such than enough of the interior of the combustion chamber is capturing the forward push in the reaction.  seems inefficient in part.

Comment: In general, to prevent stream reversal, pressure at the point of air entrance into combustion need not be higher than that in the center of combustion. Pressure of moving gas element may actually increase as the air comes to combustion. The pressure gradient will slow down the air element, but not completely stop it or reverse its velocity.